# How does a phrase differ from a clause

Tags: american-english, british-english

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/price_is_right

Is this a phrase or clause. How do they differ aside from active verb.

*A group of words that is part of, rather than the whole of, a sentence
A phrase can be long or short but it does not include the subject-verb pairing necessary to make a clause.*

Price is right is just missing  '**The**'. It has the subject verb pairing and is listed as a phrase. What is the distinction between this phrase with a verb and the ones these various definitions are describing including those phrases that only have one or the other either subject or verb.

Comment: Wiktionary is incorrect, or at least misleading.  Native speakers would normally include some kind of article, usually "the", e.g. *"**The** price is right"*.

Comment: A *phrase* is a small group of words, grammatically taking the same place of a single word.

For example, "the man on the Clapham omnibus" instead of "everyman", with "Mr Average" broadly between.

"(The…) Price is Right" is a bad example because it isn't a phrase… it's a noun, however complex.

A real phrase might be "Games such as The Price is Right" and d'you see the difference?

A clause might be "Games such as The Price is Right are good (bad or indifferent)"… which could in itself be a sentence but only depending on your context.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin This comment would make a great answer!

Comment: Thanks, Tashus, and I don't appreciate SE's differentiation between Answers and Comments…

Answer (score 1):

To quote [Study and Exam](http://www.studyandexam.com):

> Clause and phrase are parts of a sentence. A clause is a group of words that consists of a subject and a verb. A phrase is a group of words that does not consist of a subject and a verb. ... On the other hand, the remaining part of sentence, 'on the bed' is a phrase because it lacks both the subject and the verb.

[Difference Between Phrase and Clause](http://www.studyandexam.com/clause-phrase.html)